# Does F# support .NET Micro Framework

Tags: f#, .net-micro-framework

I realise this has been asked quite some time ago, but time has passed. Although F# supports .NET and .NET core, does it also support .NET Micro Framework? I wouldn't mind programming in F# for embedded applications (e.g. for the Stellaris platform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered before, and insufficiently answered. The project has been pretty quiet since 2011, and in my opinion it may be wise to instead look at [nanoframework](https://github.com/nanoframework) . Neither officially support F#, however I think the best way to figure out if it will work is to try to use it.